# Got error when run command `hbase classpath`

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I want to add hbase classpath to my spark, but I got error when I run the `hbase classpath` command.

I have the hadoop 3.2.0 set up locally with java 1.8 in env.

$ hbase classpath

/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 2364: HADOOP_ORG.APACHE.HADOOP.HBASE.UTIL.GETJAVAPROPERTY_USER: invalid variable name
/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 2459: HADOOP_ORG.APACHE.HADOOP.HBASE.UTIL.GETJAVAPROPERTY_OPTS: invalid variable name
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.GetJavaProperty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously old question, but your configuration may be wrong.

This is potentially caused by insufficient privilege. You may want to try "sudo" and the command to troubleshoot. This fixed confirmed that I had a privilege issue when the command in hadoop-functions.sh was being executed.